# Override default php settings

Tags: configuration

I am having difficulties in overriding the default PHP settings within my Drupal installation. I do not want Drupal to display E_NOTICE messages. So I wanted to override the default PHP error_reporting setting from `E_ALL` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` or from 2047 to 2039 (the corresponding error reporting values).

I added the line `ini_set('error_reporting',  2039);` in both sites/default/settings.php and sites/default/default.settings.php, but still when I go the status report page and view the PHP info file, I see the error reporting setting of PHP is still set to 2047. What am I doing wrong here? How to override the php setting?

PS: I even tried adding the line `php_value error_reporting 2039` to Drupal's .htaccess file, but there is no effect.

Comment: Do you get any error message about `ini_set()` being disabled? Did you verify it is not disabled? Notice that you should not touch the default.settings.php. Drupal doesn't use that file when running; it is just used to create the settings.php file when installing Drupal.

Comment: How about putting this `log_errors = Off` in your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

to the *settings.php* file. [Here's more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is  not working..  The setting remains the same.

Comment: do you mean that the Notice's are still displayed? But it works fine on mine. D7 btw.

Comment: Yes the notices are still getting displayed. BTW, can you check your phpinfo() for the error reporting values?

Comment: ```error_reporting 30711``` hope it helps :)